# Is there a digit separator in R like using underscore in Python?

Tags: r, separator, digit-separator, numeral-system

In Python there is a way to make large numerals more readable using the underscore, e.g.
`1000000 == 1_000_000`, as discussed [several times here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009778/what-do-underscores-in-a-number-mean). However, is there something similar in R?

Googling it just leads me to [how to format the variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals) using `format`  and `formatC`. I already tried `1_000`, `1 000`, `1'000` and `1,000` but they only produce error messages. Is there really no workaround?

Comment: Not to my knowledge... but a workaround would be to write number as string with _ or , and then use gsub to remove the _ or , as you parse them to numeric.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice hack!

Comment: I believe this is the very reason people use scientific notation. Why not just use `10e6` ?

Comment: Here is discussion on the R mailing list about the implementation of this feature: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2022-July/081874.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
as.numeric(gsub("_","", "1_000_000"))
```

Comment: If you put that in a function it would look even nicer, e.g. `no_("1_000_000")` .